# $http get call with AngularJS my API is not working

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api

I am creating a Web Application. I have created an API and when I try to make an http get call from angular, it fails. I know that my api works because I have already tested it on the browser and Postman (On Chrome). In addition, I know that my code is good because I tested it by changing the url to githubs's api (https://api.github.com/users), and the response was successful. Can anyone can help me figure out why the calls to my API don't work if both return the same (a collection of JSon objects)?

```
$http({
        method: 'GET',
        url:'http://localhost:63473/api/posts' // my api
        //url: 'https://api.github.com/users' // github api
    })
        .then(function (response) {

            // successful call
            angular.copy(response.data, viewModel.posts);
            alert("Good");

        }, function (error) {

            // call to api failed
            viewModel.errorMessage = "Failed to load posts: " + error;

        });
```

This is the response of my call from Postman

```
[
{
   "id": "6db78556-c4dc-4c7c-a969-db0d202f32fc",
   "text": "This is the second Post.",
   "postedOn": "2016-04-30T21:26:56.7886027-04:00"
},
{
   "id": "5c9d9e0b-0b23-4895-93ba-b86a36e03f84",
   "text": "Hello everyone, this is my first Post",
   "postedOn": "2016-04-30T21:26:56.7846017-04:00"
}
]
```

Comment: What error is it throwing? Check the console logs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you running the API and the $http JS on the same URL? If they are not (even if the port is different), then you need to enable CORS on your api to allow cross domain requests. Please share the response you are getting when making this call.

Thank you,
Soma.

Comment: They are not running on the same URL.

Comment: K. Please enable Cross Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) on the API so it allows requests from what ever your client URL is. Please see this link for more information [link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/security/enabling-cross-origin-requests-in-web-api)

Comment: Thank you. Just curious, by doing this can I still enforce some sort of security? Like only allowing some users from the application to make the get calls to the api...

Comment: Sure you can. You can controller the domains, Http verbs and headers that are allowed with CORS. If you want user/ client (in your case the javascript application) level security you can implement identity solutions. Please let me know if you have any other questions.

Comment: For sure. Thanks for your help @Soma